# Spring Security returns only 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-rest

My application uses Spring Boot 3 with Spring Security and JWT authentication. It is simple REST API. This is my `SecurityFilterChain`:

```java
@Bean
  protected SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      // No need for CSRF in this example
      http
          .cors()
              .and()
          .csrf().disable()
          // No authentication
          .authorizeHttpRequests()
              .requestMatchers("/login", "/register").permitAll()
              // Authentication for other requests
              .anyRequest().authenticated()
              .and()
          // Session is stateless
          .exceptionHandling()
              .authenticationEntryPoint(jwtAuthenticationEntryPoint)
              .and()
          .sessionManagement()
              .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
              .and()
          .addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
      return http.build();
  }
```

And this is my `JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint`:

```java
@Component
public class JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, "Unauthorized");
    }
}
```

I prepared exception classes as described in point 3.3 [here](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) and [here](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) like this:

```java
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
public class RecipeNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
}
```

I use them like this.

```java
if (recipeFound.isEmpty()) throw new RecipeNotFoundException();
```

I would like to send appropriate HTTP codes ex. when user tries to edit recipe that does not exist. Unfortunately I always get 401 Unauthorized. It also prevents my app from sending 500 code (I get 401 instead).

Here is my `JwtRequestFilter`:

```java
@Component
public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private final JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
    private final JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

    public JwtRequestFilter(JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService, JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil) {
        this.jwtUserDetailsService = jwtUserDetailsService;
        this.jwtTokenUtil = jwtTokenUtil;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (!request.getRequestURI().equals("/register") && !request.getRequestURI().equals("/login")) {
            final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");

            String username = null;
            String jwtToken = null;

            // Remove Bearer word from token
            if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
                try {
                    username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to get JWT Token");
                } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                    System.out.println("JWT Token has expired");
                }
            } else {
                logger.warn("JWT Token does not start with Bearer String");
            }

            // Validate token
            if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                UserDetails userDetails = this.jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

                // Configure authentication in Spring Security
                if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken =
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                    usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));

                    // Successful Authentication
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                }
            }
        }
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to permit `/error` to see the error message instead 401.

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. I have not come across this in any JWT guide.

Comment: Thanks @dur , I had the same problem after migrating to Spring Boot3/ Security6. Your other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75282801/369946 helped me to understand better this solution.

Comment: Not sure, why I didn't have this problem with Spring Boot 2 though, probably a custom error handler.