# Why is Spring Security redirecting to /error in this case?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

So I have a simple `SecurityFilterChain` configuration and a simple `AuthenticationEntrypoint` implementation.

The `AutheticationEntrypoint` implementation just writes a JSON response and the send a 403 error to the client.

The problem is that, for some reason, when I try access a protected resource without credentials, the request gets redirected to `/error` as I can see in the logs (DEBUG level).

**`SecurityConfiguration.java`**

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .httpBasic().disable()
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers()
                .frameOptions().sameOrigin()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new ApplicationAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                .and()
            .build();
    }
}
```

**`ApplicationAuthenticationEntryPoint.java`**

```java
public class ApplicationAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);
        response.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
        response.getWriter().write(mapper.createObjectNode()
                .put("timestamp", LocalDateTime.now().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.of("-3")))
                .put("message", "Access denied to resource")
                .toString());
    }
}
```

When I call a protected resource, I see the following in the logs:

```
2023-03-10T14:59:49.528-03:00 DEBUG 58236 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /test
2023-03-10T14:59:49.528-03:00 DEBUG 58236 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2023-03-10T14:59:49.529-03:00 DEBUG 58236 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error
2023-03-10T14:59:49.529-03:00 DEBUG 58236 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
```

Why there's a line "Securing GET /error"? The Spring Security filter chain is called twice due to that "redirect". Including the `ExceptionTranslationFilter`. I put a breakpoint on the the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` and the debugger falls twice on this breakpoint.

Is this `/error` that default error page from Spring Boot? If so, how? Since all the security is made on filters, it hasn't reached the MVC stack yet by the time the authentication exception occurs.

Perhaps I'm lacking knowledge on how Spring Security works.

Why is this happening?

Comment: You are not logged in, so your `ApplicationAuthenticationEntryPoint` is executed. This class is returning an error (`response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FORBIDDEN);`). This error is redirected to `/error` (default error handler). You have to permit `/error` to see the error response.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75271958/spring-boot-3-with-spring-security-intercepts-exceptions-i-dont-want-it-to

Comment: @dur . . . it really helped me. If I understood it correctly, seems like Spring Boot registers the `BasicErrorController` mapped to /error by default to the servlet container, tomcat in this case. When the `SC_FORBIDDEN` is sent in the response, tomcat delegate the global error page to the `/error` which then falls to the `BasicErrorController` to write the corresponding response.

Comment: To be sure, open the `/error` and you will see the error message. Maybe it is some other exception, I could not see in your code.

Comment: Actually you're 100% correct. Permiting /error shows the default 403 response. Customizing the BasicErrorController was enough to deal with my case.