# Spring Security — 'Full authentication is required to access this resource' for a non-existing endpoint

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

AuthenticationEntryPoint triggers even if authorization is successfully passed, when I try to go to an endpoint that does not exist. How do I make it go to a 404 page?

This is my Spring Security configuration

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    return http
            .cors().and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint()).and()
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
            .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot 3 with Spring Security Intercepts exceptions I don't want it to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75271958/spring-boot-3-with-spring-security-intercepts-exceptions-i-dont-want-it-to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to allow all requests to the `/error` path.

```java
.requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
```

Answer (score 0):

Unmitigated answer worked just fine for me! But just to complement, we can also use the dispatcher, because:

> The AuthorizationFilter runs not just on every request, but on every dispatch. This means that the REQUEST dispatch needs authorization, but also FORWARDs, ERRORs, and INCLUDEs.

So this worked as well:

```
.dispatcherTypeMatchers(DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.ERROR).permitAll()
```